# why is element undefined in CFC?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfml, coldfusion-11

I have a fairly simple CFC with a set of properties and then some basic functions related to those properties. Everything seems to work fine except a property which is an array...

```
property name="tags" type="array";
```

This is the simple declaration of the property. But then, when I try to perform an operation on it in one of the member functions, I get an error...

```
public void function addTag(thisTag) {
    var local.tags = this.getTags();
    if (thisTag.isObjectValid()) {          
        *ArrayAppend(local.tags,arguments.thisTag);*
        this.setTags(local.tags);
    }
}
```

The line with the stars is where I get an error (the stars aren't in the code)

```
Element TAGS is undefined in LOCAL.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additional Info:

1. accessors="true" is set in the component declaration
2. isObjectValid is a custom function in another CFC - it has been tested and works

Comment: Put a writedump(local) after the second line and see what you get.

Comment: Not related to your question, but isn't the combination of var and local redundant?

Comment: I get the same error, "Element TAGS is undefined in LOCAL", but now it happens on the line of the dump instead of the starred line above.

Comment: Yes, it is redundant. I added the local scope later, trying to solve this problem and forgot to remove the var. I'll clean up after I fix the problem.

Comment: writedump(local) will not throw an error.  If anything, it will return an empty struct.  In any event, what happens with writedump(this.getTags())?  Notice the trend?  When in doubt, look at your data.

Comment: I just ran getTags and it comes back undefined - not sure why that would be, given that it is defined as an array in the property statement above.

Comment: See my answer, you have NOT defined a value with your property tag. You have simply declared a variable and type which defaults to null.  This is a foreign concept to most CF devs, but quite common in other languages such as Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't set a default value for the tags property, and therefore it is null, or undefined.   You need to give it a default, or assign a value in the constructor before trying to access it.  Alternatively, you can continue as you are, but you'll want to do an isNull( local.tags ) to check and see if it has been initialized.

Comment: This is the problem though. If the type is an array, how do I give it a default value, when the default value has to be a constant?

Comment: I ended up creating an Init() function and setting ArrayNew(1) to the array properties. It seems there should be a way to default that without having to do it in the Init, though.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it. I don't understand why property defaults need to be a constant.  Perhaps there is a ticket in the Adobe bug base for that.  If not, you can add one :)